# What was the basis of the calendar during Japan's Edo period?

Tags: japan, calendar, time-keeping, edo-period

I couldn't find a proper answer on the internet, every article refers to the timeline using the Gregorian calendar.

But I'm guessing Japan didn't use this method given the fact that they weren't christian in any way. So what did they use ? Did they say something like "year 3 of the Edo period" ? Or "year 5 of the Tokugawa shogunate" ?

I'm trying to get some historical accuracy in a story I'm writing and this would be really useful for me.

Thanks in advance for any kind of answer !

(also, I am sorry if my question lacks in clarity as English is not my main language)

EDIT:

It seems the most common way used to keep track of the years at the time was the [Era system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_era_name), which is actually still used in certain situations today. Thanks to Lucian for this clarification!(see the comments for more info)

Comment: Good question. I think the Romans used the reign of emperors in the pagan era (e.g. 5th year in reign of Hadrian) so maybe something like that

Comment: I wish I were as fluent in any other language as you are in English.

Comment: See [Japanese calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_calendar), [Japanese era name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_era_name), [East Asian age reckoning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Asian_age_reckoning), and [sexagenary cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagenary_cycle).

Comment: @Lucian thank you, this is what I needed! I edited the post to include your answer.